# Validation using JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Iam new to JMeter,Iam posting data in Queue using JMeter and after posting  manually opening my UI and validating the data present UI same or not!

"Is it possible posting data(Using JMS Publiher) and validate fields in UI uisng only J-Meter"

**Note:we are not using Recording Controller concept for my script, i need validation using J-Meter**

Thanks& Regards,
ManiKanta

Comment: what's your UI ? web/mobile/desktop application/other?

Comment: its a Web application(it is a Client Network), similar like creating a account in Google,yahoo etc..

Answer (score 0):

It is.

1. For posting data into queue check out [JMS Publisher](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher) and/or [JMS Point-to-Point](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point) samplers. You might also be interested in [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) article.
2. For opening UI - use normal [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
3. For comparing expected values with the actual go for [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

Comment: thanks for the reply,but my question is like validate the response data and Client UI using Jmeter(not Using Recording Controller)